# RDD transformation and actions

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

While doing transformations on RDD, for example :-

```
firstRDD=spark.textFile("hdfs://...") 

secondRDD=firstRDD.filter(someFunction);

thirdRDD = secondRDD.map(someFunction);
```

Does first, second and third RDD store the value in RAM or when we perform action on the final thirdRDD like `result = thirdRDD.count()` then it will store the data?

Answer (score 2):

- Until `count` is called there is no processing at all.
- None of the operations stores any data in memory, excluding constant memory allocation required for the `count`.
- Rows materialized during `count` can be immediately discarded and garbage collected.

Comment: Okay this means firstRDD=spark.textFile("hdfs://...") 
Will not store the text file in RAM?? This means in transformations there is no in memory read/write? During transformation somewhere it should store the operator functions right?

Comment: In-Memory, i.e. data inside RDD is stored in memory as much (size) and long (time) as possible. here it is saying that RDD data resides in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, an RDD will load value only when an action is called upon in chain. In this case, it will load values only when count operation is executed and will load only data until condition specified inside function of "filter" is specified.

It will not load data and keep it in ram. It can If you call method persist on one RDD. Otherwise, it will load data from scratch next time any action is operated.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Okay this means firstRDD=spark.textFile("hdfs://...") 
Will store the text file in RAM??

Comment: If you do not call persist on `firstRdd`, it will not store text file in RAM

Comment: Okay got it thanks :)
Do you know how spark standalone manage fault tolerant?

Comment: I'm also new to spark and learning it ;), however, I can't explain how spark manages fault tolerance internally in a cluster, but I can tell you that spark stores information of all the transformation performed on any RDD in a graph like structure. And if any node fails then it re calculate the RDD from that graph